# in .htaccess, how to detect a part of a cookie name with Regex?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, cookies

I'm setting up a .htaccess file to prevent access to anything within a folder unless a certain cookie is set. The issue is that the cookie name can vary as a certain ID number is attached to the end of it, and I have no control over that.

The cookie I have setup can be (frm_form30, frm_form31, etc.).

Here's the .htaccess code I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*\bfrm_form(?:\d*\.)?\d+*.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [NC,L]
```

I'm using this:

```
\bfrm_form(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

as the regex that will detect any cookie starting with frm_form and ending with a two digit number. Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if I'm doing something completely wrong?

The code works if I use the full cookie name (ex. frm_form30), so the rest of the file --I think-- is alright.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it intentional that you redirect to the home page? Wouldn't it be better to send a `403 Forbidden` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a two digit number just use `\bfrm_form\d\d` or `\bfrm_form\d{2}`.

Your regex matches any number, with decimal part or not.

Simplify your expression and send A Forbidden header instead of redirecting :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bfrm_form\d\d\b [NC]
RewriteRule .* [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*frm_form+(?:\d*\.)?\d+.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com [NC,L]
```

Let me know if you think there is a better way. Thanks!